# Inverting colours of an image callback in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit, fullpage.js

I've changed the slide arrows to my own png, black arrows but on some slides, which have darker background I want to invert them so they are white.

```
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
```

works just fine, but how to trigger this only on slides that using a callback?

Quick animation of the invert parameter 0% > 100% would be a cool bonus. Thanks.

Comment: About the animation - you need to use transitions: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you want to trigger the new css only for slides with specific IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know about `fullPage.js`, but reading through the [docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks), I found that you can customize a callback that fires when leaving or entering a slide.

I think this is what you want:

**jsFiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/ym3snhu4/1/

*Notice that I'm only using `-webkit-filter` to invert the color, so this might not work in other non-webkit browsers. So test this in Chrome, for instance. Otherwise, just add more prefixes to the filter property when adding/removing the style. It depends on how you are changing your arrows, but you can, for instance (with fullPage.js), just change the border-color instead of using filter.*

Basically, we are using the **afterSlideLoad** and the **onSlideLeave** callbacks to achieve this. Here's the code with the explanation in comments. It's pretty straightforward. My comments are way longer than the code needed, just hoping it's clear.

**Example HTML:**

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1"> Slide 1 - Index 0 </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2"> Slide 2 - Index 1 </div>
    <div class="slide slide-dark" data-anchor="slide3"> Slide 3 - Index 2 <br> I'm black </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4"> Slide 4 - Index 3</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Just take into consideration the callback methods.
// The body selector is the one I used in the jsFiddle, keep whatever you have.

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').fullpage({

        // The name is self explanatory. 
        // Fires when a a slide has finished loading
        // and returns info about the slide.
        // This is helpful so we can know when we are on the
        // darker slide(s)
        afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) { 

            // Notice that in the HTML I set the data-anchor attribute, 
            // since that can help us be specific about what slide we are in. 
            // Otherwise, just use the index, which is probably a good idea 
            // since onSlideLeave doesn't return the slideAnchor parameter, 
            // for some reason.
            // Change the if statement to whatever fits your needs.
            // Check what index and/or anchor your darker slides are.

            if(slideAnchor === 'slide3' || slideIndex === 2) {

                // This adds the invert filter to the controlArrow(s),
                // effectively reversing their color WHEN inside of
                // this specific slide.
                // (In this example, slideIndex 2 with anchor 'slide3').
                $('.fp-controlArrow').css('-webkit-filter', 'invert(100%)');
            }
        },

        // This fires when leaving a slide.
        // This will be helpful to return the arrows to their 
        // default color. (When we know we've inverted them beforehand)
        onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {

            // We inverted the color of the arrows in slide 3.
            // When leaving this slide, we roll them back to their
            // original color, by setting the filter to 'none'.
            // I don't know why this 'event' doesn't return the
            // slideAnchor parameter, so we will just use the index
            // in here, which is slideIndex === 2 for 'slide3'.
            // Again, change the if logic to fit your needs, i.e. add
            // more slides.

            if(slideIndex === 2) {

                // This removes the filter, arrows go back to their
                // original color.

                $('.fp-controlArrow').css('-webkit-filter', 'none');

            }
        }
    });
});
```

**And the CSS needed for the smooth transition on filter** (change the animation speed to whatever you wish):

```
.fp-controlArrow {
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
```

Comment: No problemo! Glad it was useful.